# Running JUnit tests with and without before/after hooks

Tags: java, junit

I have a situation where I need to be able to run a suite of JUnit tests under 2 different "modes":

- With the first mode, use `@Before` and `@After` annotations/methods are used; but...
- With the second mode, do not use these annotations/methods, but run the same `@Test` methods

For example:

```
public class WidgetTest {
    @Before
    void start() {
        // Do some start up work.
    }

    @After
    void stop() {
        // Do some shutdown work.
    }

    @Test
    public void testWidget() {
        // Given/When/Then, etc.
    }
}
```

In "Mode #1", I want `@Before` and `@After` methods (`start()` and `stop()` respectively) to execute before/after `testWidget()`. But in "Mode #2", I would **only** want the `testWidget()` method to fire.

The best I can come up with is:

```
public class WidgetTest {
    private boolean useHooks;

    // Ctor, getter and setter for 'useHooks'.

    @Before
    void start() {
        if(useHooks) {
            // Do some start up work.
        }
    }

    @After
    void stop() {
        if(useHooks) {
            // Do some shutdown work.
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testWidget() {
        // Given/When/Then, etc.
    }
}
```

But then this presents an additional problem: *How do I inject `useHooks` into my test suite?* It is also kind of hacky, and I guess I'm hoping that JUnit supports this kind of use case out of the box.

Is there a way to accomplish this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Check out `@Category` annotation

Comment: Thanks @robocoder (+1) - not a bad suggestion, but then it means I'll need to define my `testWidget()` method in two places (once in the test classes that uses these start/stop methods, and again in the test class that doesn't use them). To me this is way too much dupe code seeing that each test class will have dozens of test methods, and I have hundreds of test classes. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to consider this solution:

- Write a custom JUnit runner
- Add a VM param to switch between the 2 needed modes

Here is the code of the custom runner I've come up with:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters;
import org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class MyJUnitRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    private final boolean runBeforesAndAfters = System.getProperty("run-befores-and-afters") != null;

    public MyJUnitRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withBefores(FrameworkMethod method, Object target, Statement statement) {
        List<FrameworkMethod> befores = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        if (runBeforesAndAfters) {
            befores = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(Before.class);
        }
        return befores.isEmpty() ? statement : new RunBefores(statement, befores, target);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withAfters(FrameworkMethod method, Object target, Statement statement) {
        List<FrameworkMethod> afters = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        if (runBeforesAndAfters) {
            afters = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(After.class);
        }
        return afters.isEmpty() ? statement : new RunAfters(statement, afters, target);
    }

}
```

All you have to do it start the JUnits VM with this option added: `-Drun-befores-and-afters` and annotate your test class with `@RunWith(MyJUnitRunner.class)` and then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests), so you code will look like this (not tested)

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class WidgetTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[] {true, false});
    }

    private boolean useHooks

    public WidgetTest(booelan useHooks) {
        this.useHooks = useHooks;
    }
    ....
}
```